# How to connect user's facebook account with an account in my app?

Tags: ios, facebook

I want to add a possibility to use my app via facebook account. What requests should I make to make it possible?
For example, I create an account on my website, so

1. I should connect it with my facebook account, and
2. At the login flow in my app understand, that this facebook's account is basically my website's account.

How it's possible?

Comment: -1: This question was asked so many times before. Why not using the search function before writing a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mechanism for this is called Facebook Connect (or Single-Sign-On = SSO). Facebook provides API to connect both a regular website and an iOS app to a Facebook account. Facebook provides some excellent documentation, here is their iOS documentation for example: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

Facebook Connect gives you two main features:

1. Let the users login to your website/app using their Facebook account. This means they don't need to register separately to your service if they're already registered with Facebook.
2. Once they connect with Facebook, the website/app owner receives a token which lets you access some information about the user. For example, see the user's name, Facebook photo, email address, and in some cases also grant permissions to post on this user's Facebook wall.

Let's go over the different possible flows for a website:

1. The user has already registered his own account on your website, and you let him connect their account to their Facebook account too.
2. The user did not register his own account on your website. Instead, he logs into your website using his Facebook account. Once you notice this new user logged in, you automatically create a new account for him and take the info (such as email address) from their Facebook profile.

The flows for an app are pretty much the same. The main benefit for an app, is that people don't like to register for apps. Users don't like too many usernames and passwords. You will probably have more logged-in users if you allow them to use their existing Facebook account instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Hi @talkol, how about the password? How can you create that? And another question, is the ID always the same or it can change? Thanks